# Consolidation of two windows services into one service

Tags: c#, windows-services

✍️ I have written 2 windows services using C#.

▶  **1st service:**

Read the data from the office (local) database and write the selected data to a csv file and output to a given location.

▶  **2nd service:**

Read the data from the csv file and write the data back to the MySQL database (online website).

**----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

The main intention of this project is to let customers view their Job details via the website.

For that to be happen above 2 windows services have been initialised.

The next step is to merge these 2 services into one service and run it as a single service.

I am looking for a way to integrate these two services into one.

Comment: Not sure why two services, Instead of writing to CSV file from the First service, you can directly write to DB?

Comment: @saTech It is not possible to write data from a local (manager) database directly to MySQL database. It should be in 2 steps like I discussed above. Despite of that I need to integrate these 2 services into one. I need to know how the coding should be structured. Thanks!